# How to asynchronously map over sequence

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I want to iterate over a sequence of objects and return the first non-null of an async call.

The point is to perform some kind of async operation that might fail, and I have a series of fallbacks that I want to try in order, one after the other (i.e. lazily / not in parallel).

I've tried to do something similar to what I'd do if it were a sync call:

```
// ccs: List<CurrencyConverter>
override suspend fun getExchangeRateAsync(from: String, to: String) =
  ccs.asSequence()
    .map { it.getExchangeRateAsync(from, to) }
    .firstOrNull { it != null }
    ?: throw CurrencyConverterException()
```

IntelliJ complains:

> Suspension functions can only be called within coroutine body

Edit: To clarify, this works as expected if mapping on a List, but I want to see how I'd do this on a sequence.

So I guess this is because the map lambda isn't suspended? But I'm not sure how to actually do that. I tried a bunch of different ways but none seemed to work. I couldn't find any examples.

If I re-write this in a more procedural style using a `for` loop with an async block, I can get it working:

```
override suspend fun getExchangeRateAsync(from: String, to: String) {
    for (cc in ccs) {
        var res: BigDecimal? = async {
            cc.getExchangeRateAsync(from, to)
        }.await()

        if (res != null) {
            return res
        }
    }

    throw CurrencyConverterException()
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `async-await` around a `suspend fun` call? Looks redundant.

Comment: Just for reference, your second example can look like this: `for (cc in ccs) cc.getExchangeRateAsync(from, to)?.also { return it }; throw CurrencyConverterException()`

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest replacing Sequence with Flow. Flow api and behavior is pretty much same as for Sequence, but with suspending options.

```
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html
```

**Code:**

```
override suspend fun getExchangeRateAsync(from: String, to: String) =
    ccs.asFlow()
    .map { it.getExchangeRateAsync(from, to) }
    .firstOrNull { it != null }
    ?: throw CurrencyConverterException()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error, because `Sequence` is lazy by default and it's `map` isn't an inline function, so it's scope isn't defined

You can avoid using `Sequence` by creating a list of lazy coroutines

```
// ccs: List<CurrencyConverter>
suspend fun getExchangeRateAsync(from: String, to: String) =
    ccs
    .map { async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { it.getExchangeRateAsync(from, to) } }
    .firstOrNull { it.await() != null }
    ?.getCompleted() ?: throw Exception()
```

This doesn't give any errors and seems to be working. But I'm not sure it's an idiomatic way

Comment: I tried this before; the error is the same on the await(): "Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body"

Comment: Just to say, yes, it works fine if mapped against the List; but that's the point of this Q -- I don't know how you'd write idiomatic code that'd work on a sequence.

Comment: @chroder I've added another solution, not sure it's idiomatic

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I found the suggestion in [How to asynchronously map over sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969410/how-to-asynchronously-map-over-sequence) to be very intuitive.  The code at https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines-examples/blob/master/examples/suspendingSequence/suspendingSequence.kt defines `SuspendingIterator` which allows `next()` to suspend, then builds `SuspendingSequence` on top of it.  Unfortunately, you need to duplicate extension functions like `flatMap()`, `filter()`, etc. since `SuspendingSequence` can't be related to `Sequence`, but I did this and am much happier with the result than using a Channel.